# Lookup table: array vs. switch/case performance

Tags: php, arrays, performance, lookup-tables

In a PHP application, I have a very large constant (literal) lookup table in the form of a three dimensional array with string keys in the first two dimensions, and the third dimension being non-associative, with many repetitions in the second level (some whole third-dimension arrays appear repeated).

Coming from compiled languages like C++, I prefer such lookup tables because they produce almost no runtime cost (only cache-misses in the code are a problem). So I defined it in PHP like this:

```
$table = array(
    '182-0' => array(
        '221-0' => array()
    ), 
    '184-0' => array(
        '197-0' => array('1.9','1.10','1.11','1.12','1.13','1.14','1.15','1.16','1.17','1.18'), 
        '201-0' => array('1.9','1.10','1.11','1.12','1.13','1.14','1.15','1.16','1.17','1.18'), 
        '221-0' => array('1.19','1.20','1.21','1.22','1.23','1.24','1.25','1.26','1.27','1.28'), 
        '221-1' => ...,
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

This array consumes about 1 megabyte in source code and is fully static. All of this code is executed unconditionally in order to create the complete lookup table, then one third-dimension array is **only used once** per request:

```
// once per request, for given $a and $b:
foreach ($table[$a][$b] as $item) {
    ...
}
```

I guess that there might be better choices for code like this. I guess the core problem of the above code is that the array is built up on every request dynamically, but since it is only used once this effort is pretty much useless.

What is a good alternative to the above code? I'd like to save both source code size as well as runtime cost.

Should I rewrite this as branches? Are there even better options, specifically suited for constant lookup tables?

I'm thinking of a "branch"-based solution like this (note the case-fall-through to avoid duplication of the third-level-arrays):

```
function table($a, $b) {
    switch ($a) {
    case '182-0':
        switch ($b) {
        case '221-0':
            return array();
        default:
            return null;
        }

    case '184-0':
        switch ($b) {
        case '197-0':
        case '201-0':
            return array('1.9','1.10','1.11','1.12','1.13','1.14','1.15','1.16','1.17','1.18');
        case '221-0':
            return array('1.19','1.20','1.21','1.22','1.23','1.24','1.25','1.26','1.27','1.28');
        ...
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
    ...

    return null;
}
```

Then use it with:

```
// once per request, for given $a and $b:
foreach (table($a, $b) as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to suggest anything as we have no idea what is the end expectation - what are you trying to do?